# How to enter a sum derived from awk in the middle of text output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, scripting

I am trying to print a sum in the middle of a line. My script prompts for a user name and then pulls a total number of processes and a total of time for that user from a file.

I want to print a sentence with the totals in the middle of the sentence.

Using `awk` I can get the totals  for processes and minutes but am unable to print the results of an equation in the middle of a sentence. My equation's result shows up after the sentence.

I feel like I need to use an anchor like in HTML. I am using PuTTY.

```
 oliver|Login|100
 smith|Login|20
 oliver|Time|25
 oliver|Time|25
 smith|Time|20
 Anne|Login|100

Example: User name? oliver
oliver has run 3 processes for a total of 150 minutes

 case $choice" in
   1) echo -n "User name?"
    read username
    echo "$username has run processes for a total of minutes"
    ;;
```

I would like to get a total for processes and minutes for the specific user name entered. Then insert those numbers into the sentence where they belong.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. Could you [edit] your post with: what you're using, what you've tried so far, example(s) of what you want the behaviour to be, and example(s) of what you're seeing now?

Comment: @Jake Please verify that the edited question is correct.  More importantly, please edit and show the _actual code_ that was _not_ doing what you want.   Describing the incorrect output is not enough, you need to _show both_ the _code_ and the resulting _output_ whether it's correct or not.  Thank you and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script takes its args from the command line rather than a prompt.  This makes it easier to re-use from other scripts and allows the user to specify multiple usernames.

```sh
$ cat jake.sh 
#! /bin/sh

inputfile='input.txt'

for u in "$@" ; do
    awk -F'|' -v u="$u" '$1 == u { sum = sum + $3 ; count++} 
        END {print u " has run " count " processes for a total of " \
             sum " minutes."}' < "$inputfile"
done
```

Note how the shell script passes the shell variable `$u` to the awk script via the `-v u="$u"` option.  That avoids having to use double-quotes around the awk script to use the shell `$u` directly...as that would require escaping every instance of `$1`, `$3`, and every `"` in the awk script with a backslash `\`.

The input is same as in your example:

```
$ cat input.txt 
oliver|Login|100
smith|Login|20
oliver|Time|25
oliver|Time|25
smith|Time|20
Anne|Login|100
```

And here's the output:

```
$ ./jake.sh oliver smith Anne
oliver has run 3 processes for a total of 150 minutes.
smith has run 2 processes for a total of 40 minutes.
Anne has run 1 processes for a total of 100 minutes.
```

If you really wanted it to prompt for the username, the script would look like this:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

inputfile='input.txt'

echo -n "User name?"
read username

awk -F'|' -v u="$username" '$1 == u { sum = sum + $3 ; count++} 
    END {print u " has run " count " processes for a total of " \
         sum " minutes."}' < "$inputfile"
```

Comment: I'll also mention for OP's benefit (as cas mentioned to me himself) that perl is a great language for when you need to combine shell features with awk features.  In this case, awk works fine, as above.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking of thank you.